# Would it be fair to say heart disease, diabetes (II), and Alzheimer's disease are all the same health issue expressed different ways?

Tags: diabetes, heart-disease, alzheimers

Heart disease, type 2 diabetes, and I believe Alzheimer's as well, seem to all be the result of the body's plumbing being clogged up by fat and cholesterol deposits. Exercise, a diet low in artificial fructose, saturated fat, and trans fats, but high fiber, seems to be effective at reducing your risks.

Diabetes II is the result of insulin not being effective because of inter-cellar build ups; heart disease is when your heart cannot get blood to function because of build up in the vessels that supply it.

Would it be fair to categorize these health issues as different manifestations of the same disease, similarly to how we call many different kinds of cancer "cancer"?

Evidence that Alzheimer's may be a form of diabetes: http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2769828

Comment: No, not really. They all have similar causes, but both symptoms and treatment varies so much you can hardly call them similar aspects of a disease. Also, I’m not aware of the Heart Disease, there are myocardial infractions, malfunctioning heart valves and many more diseases connected to the heart.

Comment: In what way is Alzheimer's caused by clogged up plumbing?

Comment: @CareyGregory https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2769828/

Comment: Better for that link to be in the question so I added it.

Comment: If that were the case, then Avascular Necrosis of the femoral head would also be the "same disease" as it is caused by fatty emboli blocking the tiny veins in the femur.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, Alzheimer's is considered by some to be [type III diabetes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2769828/) and the pathology induced is a combination of hypertension, hyperlipidaemia, and elevated glycation products.

Comment: Interesting study, haven't come across that one before. However, your answer doesn't address "heart disease", and could arguably be fleshed out a bit more. If you [edit] it a bit, you'll definitely have my +1.